# List of classes question c#

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics

I have a class contain many variables, something like that

```
class test
{    
  internal int x , y ;
  internal string z;
}
```

I created a list of this class `list<test> c`

I want to do the following:

1. test if all the list items contain the same x
2. get the list's item that has z = "try"

I need a quick and fast way , instead of iterate though the entire items

Any suggestion please ,

Comment: Any way you choose is going to iterate through the entire list. It's just a matter of what the code *looks like*.

Comment: @Adam: It may not need to iterate over the *entire* list. The first item may have z="try", and the second item may have a different value for x.

Comment: @Jon: Sure, but my point was that the algorithm itself doesn't have any particular optimizations to bring it below O(n).

Comment: @Adam: Sure, agreed. (And even Dictionary would have to look through the whole lot if they all had the same hash code :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

LINQ to Objects is your friend. For the first:

```
bool allSameX = list.All(t => t.x == list[0].x);

Test firstTry = list.First(t => t.z == "try");
Test firstTryOrNull = list.FirstOrDefault(t => t.z == "try");
```

The first one depends on there *being* at least one value of course. Alternatives might be:

```
bool allSameX = !list.Select(t => t.x)
                     .Distinct()
                     .Skip(1)
                     .Any();
```

In other words, once you've gone past the first distinct value of `x`, there shouldn't be any more. One nice aspect of this is that as soon as it spots the second distinct value, it will stop looking - as does the first line (the `All` version) of course.

LINQ is wonderfully flexible, and well worth looking into closely.

EDIT: If you need to do the latter test ("find an element with a particular value for z") for multiple different values, you might want a dictionary or a lookup, e.g.

```
// If there are duplicate z values
var lookup = list.ToLookup(t => t.z);

// If z values are distinct
var dictionary = list.ToDictionary(t => t.z);
```

Without *some* pre-work, there's no way of performing the queries you want without iterating over at least *some* of the list.

Comment: +1. While the op says he doesn't want to iterate the entire list, that's obviously not possible.

Comment: @Adam: Do you know, I misread that as "I need a fast and quick way to iterate through the entire items."

Comment: if the class contains array of string, how to check if there a difference in them , any suggestion

Comment: @AMH: What do you mean by "if there a difference in them"? Would {"a", "b"} be the same as {"b", "a"} for example? This sounds like it's out of the scope of the initial question, to be honest.

Comment: @AMH: Then I suggest you ask a new question with the specific details of what you're trying to achieve - and *only* that part.

Answer (score 2):

You can use linq. Here is a link to small examples that will help you a lot for future too http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746

Comment: :) Jon beat me to it while I was typing on my mobile with my stubby fingers.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a custom collection class instead of a list, and put the search smarts into this e.g. 
add a method AllItemsHaveSameX() and a private bool field allItemsHaveSameX
expose a dictionary keyed by the search strings with the index of the item that has that value.

When adding/removing items:
You would re-evaluate allItemsHaveSameX
Add/remove from your private dictionary.